# conversion from fluorescent to halogen lights

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am try to take a connection that was originally used for a fluorescent light with a black wire and a white wire and use the same two wires with a halogen light that has a white wire, a black wire, and a yellow and green wire. Is it possible to make this conversion and if so, how?

Comment: Wire colors don't mean a whole lot (other than by code, white can only be neutral -- but you can't count on that). Can you explain what each wire is connected to now? Are you trying to use the same fixture? The first thing that comes to mind in why you'd have the different colored wires is you're looking at a florescent ballast, but that's opposite of what you said. A picture or two would go a very long way here..

Comment: Do you mean that one of the wires is green with a yellow stripe? ( That would be for a ground wire )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on exactly what your old arrangement was and what the new arrangement is, photos of everything would help make this clear.

### Fluorescent

Fluorescent lights have electronics components associated with them, for example a starter and ballast. You need to identify where these are and make sure you remove them.

[image]
<sup>*From [HowStuffWorks](http://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/repair/how-to-install-a-fluorescent-lamp.htm)*</sup>

### Halogen

Many Halogen lamps also do not work directly from your normal house electric supply (e.g. 110V AC or 230V AC depending on country etc) but need a transformer. You need to be sure the bulb is rated for the full voltage or that a new light fitting includes a suitable transformer.

[image]

### Incandescent Compatibility

Some compact fluorescent bulbs and some halogen bulbs are designed for use with the standard light fittings that are/were used for ordinary traditional incandescent bulbs. In this case, the associated electronics are built into the base of the bulb. If your old and new bulbs are both of this type, you should have no need for rewiring the bulb-holder/lamp-fitting.

[image: incandescent][image: CFL][image: halogen]
<sup>*interchangeable incandescent, fluorescent and halogen bulbs*</sup>

### Earth/Ground

The green/yellow wire is for a protective earth/ground connection. This suggests that your new fitting has exposed metal parts that could present a safety hazard if a fault develops in the fitting or in the wiring supplying the fitting. You need to check the building electrical code or regulations that apply in your country/state. In the worst case, you may need to run a new earth wire or have an electrician certify that your earthing arrangements (or lack of) is safe.

Comment: Yea this is good. Just remove the ballasts and use the wires that were on the 220v/110v side for your new light bulb. The wires and fittings on the bulb sides can be recycled, disposed or sold (they can be worth a bit sometimes!)